# After calling the function from within it self the previous values remain

Tags: python, mysql-python

I created a function called block_unblocked which just changes a value from a mysql column called ABlocked. I wanted it to not accpect inputs with spaces in 'user' so I decided to call the function again if input had spaces. But when I move onto the next step all the previous values in 'user' is saved.

Code:

```
def block_unblock():
    try:
        while True:
            user = input("Enter the desired ID: ")
            if " " in user:
                print("The ID should not contain spaces")
                block_unblock()
            # Check if the user exists in the PASSWORD table using a parameterized query
            cur.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM password WHERE ID = %s)", (user,))
            result = cur.fetchone()

            if result[0] == 0:  # If the user is NOT IN PASSWORD list.
                print("User not found in the list.")
                continue

            # Check if the user exists in the PASSWORD table using a parameterized query
            cur.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM password WHERE ID = %s)", (user,))
            result = cur.fetchone()

            if result[0] == 0:  # If the user is NOT IN PASSWORD list.
                print("User not found...")
                again = input("What would you like to do from here?\n1: Try another ID\n2: Exit\n")
                again = numinput_taker(again, "Please provide a valid input", ['1', '2'])

                #If the user input was 1 it will loop from start.
                if again == 2:
                    break

            elif result[0] == 1:  # If the user IS IN PASSWORD list.
                opr = input("Type:\n1: Unblock\n2: Block\n")
                opr = numinput_taker(opr, "Please provide a valid input", ['1', '2'])

                if opr == 1:  # Unblocking
                    cur.execute("SELECT ABlocked FROM password WHERE ID = %s", (user,))
                    result = cur.fetchone()
                    if result[0] == "n":  # If that user currently IS NOT BLOCKED.
                        print("This user is not blocked")
                        again = input("What would you like to do from here?\n1: Try another ID\n2: Exit\n")
                        again = numinput_taker(again, "Please provide a valid input", ['1', '2'])
                        if again == 2:
                            break
                    elif result[0] == "y":  # If that user IS currently BLOCKED.
                        cur.execute("UPDATE password SET ABlocked = 'n' WHERE ID = %s", (user,))
                        connection.commit()
                        print("The user has been unblocked.")
                        break

                elif opr == 2:  # Blocking
                    cur.execute("SELECT ABlocked FROM password WHERE ID = %s", (user,))
                    result = cur.fetchone()
                    if result[0] == "y":  # If that user currently IS BLOCKED.
                        print("This user is already blocked")
                        again = input("What would you like to do from here?\n1: Try another ID\n2: Exit\n")
                        again = numinput_taker(again, "Please provide a valid input", ['1', '2'])
                        if again == 2:
                            break
                    elif result[0] == "n":  # If that user is currently NOT BLOCKED.
                        cur.execute("UPDATE password SET ABlocked = 'y' WHERE ID = %s", (user,))
                        connection.commit()
                        print("The user has been blocked.")
                        break

    except ms.Error as e:
        print("Error connecting to the database:", e)
```

Output:

```
Enter the desired ID: 1 2
The ID should not contain spaces
Enter the desired ID:  3 4
The ID should not contain spaces
Enter the desired ID: 1
Type:
1: Unblock
2: Block
2
The user has been blocked.
Type:
1: Unblock
2: Block
2
Error connecting to the database: 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ' 3 4'
Type:
1: Unblock
2: Block
2
This user is already blocked
What would you like to do from here?
1: Try another ID
2: Exit
```

Comment: Try adding a return right after the recursive call so that you don't run the rest of the code on bad input.

Comment: Adding return did the job, im not sure if im supposed to use comments for this.

Comment: casually, if you find you have a `try:except` with a lot of content, making the internals a new function will make it nicer to deal with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity